# Making a table-like structure in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to create a table-like structure that would contain variables and simple calculations.I would like to make the structure my output, connecting it to other calculation that takes place before. And after it all, there would be a total in the end. 
 Please view picture for better understanding

[image]

And here is my code:

```
string First;
            string Last;
            First = "Cristiano";
            Last = " Ronaldo";
            Console.Write("Please enter student name <First Last>: ");
            Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.WriteLine("*************NOTE**********************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Be sure to include decimal point for scores.            ***");
            Console.WriteLine("***     !!!All score should range from 0.00 to 100.00 !!    ***");
            Console.WriteLine("***                                                         ***");
            Console.WriteLine("*** For example : 80.50                                     ***");
            Console.WriteLine("***************************************************************");

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            double Exam_1 = -1;
            double Exam_2;
            double Exam_3;
            double Assignment_1;
            double Assignment_2;

            Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
            Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            var exitProgram = false;
            var errorCount = 0;

            while (Exam_1 < 0.0 || Exam_1 > 100.0)
            {
                Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
                Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                ++errorCount;
                ErrorCount(errorCount);
            }

            Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 2 <Example: 0.0>: ");
            Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            errorCount = 0;
            while (Exam_2 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
            {
                Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 2 <Example: 95.0>:");
                Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                ++errorCount;
                ErrorCount(errorCount);
            }

            Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 3 <Example: 60.8>: ");
            Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            errorCount = 0;
            while (Exam_3 < 0.0 || Exam_3 > 100.0)
            {
                Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 3 <Example: 95.0>:");
                Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                ++errorCount;
                ErrorCount(errorCount);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
            Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            errorCount = 0;
            while (Assignment_1 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
            {
                Console.Write("Assignment score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
                Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                ++errorCount;
                ErrorCount(errorCount);
            }

            Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 2 <Example: 23.46>: ");
            Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            errorCount = 0;
            while (Assignment_2 < 0.0 || Assignment_2 > 100.0)
            {
                Console.Write("Assignment score can not be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 2 <Example: 56.0>: ");
                Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                ++errorCount;
                ErrorCount(errorCount);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.WriteLine(" -------------- OUTPUT ---------------");

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.Write("Student: ");
            Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

public static void ErrorCount(int errorCount)
    {
        if (errorCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***** Invalid input entered. PROGRAN WILL END. PLease consult the user manual and restart the prrogram. ***** ");

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            Console.Write("Press any key to exit . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Maybe a DataTable? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So what is your question? Be more specific. You'd better format your code and paste only relevant pieces. The code should represent a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (all opened braces are closed).

Comment: Maybe just a simple `Dictionary<t>`? Or you could go `IEnumerable<T>`/`List<T>`.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to edit your question so it is clear what you are asking. To me, it sounds like you might want a Windows Form using a `DataGrid` or something to display some output from user input. I'm just making assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a table-like data structure to format the output of your code like that.  You can simply use string formatting.

In fact, having a table-like data structure will not result in the output that you seek.  You will have to use string-formatting to get what you want.

The obvious "table-like" data structure is to use a two-dimensional array of objects, but that would be a bad design decision.  A better approach would be to have a Student class that will contain lists for different types of grades and have methods for their calculation and printing the results to the console.

Comment: Okay, I would look to your recommendation, and fill you in on what I get